# mat-expansion-panel with animation is dispalyed open then collapas

Tags: angular, animation, mat-expansion-panel

I have a plain list on  with an add button below:

html:

```
   <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items" [@itemAnimation]>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{item.title}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{item.description}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <p>{{item.content}}</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>

   <button id="add-entry" (click)="onAddEntryClicked()" type="button">
```

- List item

ts:

```
  items = [
        { title: 'Item 1', description: 'Description of item 1', content: 'Content of item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2', description: 'Description of item 2', content: 'Content of item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3', description: 'Description of item 3', content: 'Content of item 3' }
    ];

    onAddEntryClicked() {
        this.items.push({description: 'description', content: 'content', title: 'title'});
    }
```

The issue is that I have an animation on the list, `[@itemAnimation]` which is configured as follow:

```
animations: [
    trigger('itemAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0,
                height: '0px'}),
            animate('500ms', style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 })),
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({ opacity: 1, height: '*'}),
            animate('500ms', style({ height: '0px', opacity: 0 })),
        ]),
    ])
]
```

The problem is that upon new item addition, the new panel is first shown by default as opened, and the when animation is done, it collapses. Same thing on page load, with the exisiting items: they first appear opened and when fully load - the collaps.

How can I avoid this behavior, that the panels should be shown currectly by default?

Thanks,
Devora

Comment: Add [expanded]="true" property on matExpensionPanel component.

Comment: I get this message: Property expanded is not provided by any applicable directives nor by mat-expansion-panel element

Comment: Make sure MatExpansionModule is imported.  <mat-expansion-panel
    [expanded]="true"